# OCMClassMock and OCMStrictClassMock

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I am new in [OCMock 3](http://ocmock.org/reference/), I see there are two methods:

```
OCMClassMock(cls): creates a new nice class mock object
OCMStrictClassMock(cls): creates a class mock object
```

I read the document, but I feel still confused & have two questions:

1. What exactly the difference between `OCMClassMock(cls)` and `OCMStrictClassMock(cls)` ?
2. When should I use `OCMClassMock(cls)` and when should I use `OCMStrictClassMock(cls)`?

**====UPDATE====**

Can I understand as `OCMClassMock(cls)` is partial mock that the real implementation still run when call method on it and `OCMStrictClassMock(cls)` is a full mock like a skeleton without real implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I understand as `OCMClassMock(cls)` is partial mock that the real
>   implementation still run when call method on it

This describes `OCMPartialMock`.

> `OCMStrictClassMock(cls)` is a full mock like a skeleton without real
>   implementation?

This is an accurate general description of `OCMClassMock`.

From the reference you linked:

> [`OCMStrictClassMock`] Creates a mock object in strict mode. By
>   default mocks are nice, they return nil (or the correct default value
>   for the return type) for whatever method is called. In contrast,
>   strict mocks raise an exception when they receive a method that was
>   not explicitly expected.

So as you said, `OCMClassMock` is like a skeleton of an instance where you only stub the methods that you need to use. The difference between `OCMClassMock` and `OCMStrictClassMock` is that the former will simply return nil for a method that you haven't explicitly stubbed, whereas the latter will throw an exception if you call a method on it that you haven't explicitly stubbed.